# django processes interfering with each other

Tags: python, django

I think my problem might have something to do with the multi-threaded-ness of Django, but let me know what your thoughts are.

I have a Django web project which will eventually be accessed by multiple users. Through the interface the users will be able to kick off calculations using a module called spiceypy. This is a module which allows you to compute relative position and velocity of planetary objects, spacecraft, etc.

Spiceypy requires loading a 'kernel set' (aka 'kernel library') before performing the computations. The kernel set includes information about a spacecraft trajectory, among other things.

In my project, different users might choose to use different kernel sets. I have a Django Form which allows you to **select** the kernel set, then perform the calculations.

The calculations are done inside my Class Based View's post() method.

So, the post method looks something like this.

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data

        spiceypy.furnsh(data['kernel_set']) # THIS LOADS THE KERNEL SET SELECTED BY USER
        spiceypy.<computations>   # THIS PERFORMS VARIOUS SPICEYPY COMPUTATIONS
        spiceypy.unload()  # THIS UNLOADS THE KERNEL SET

        return self.form_valid(form)
```

I'm finding that if multiple users kick off the computations around the same time, there is interference. E.g. Say User A loads Kernel Set A, and calculations start. Then, before computations are complete, User B loads Kernel Set B, and kick off their computations. *I'm finding that the computations for User A ends up using the wrong kernel set (i/e. the kernel set selected by User B.)*

This is likely caused by the Django development server being multi-threaded instead of single threaded. Is that the case?

I don't really want to make it single-threaded (would that be a solution?) since some of the computations take a while, and I don't want users to have to "wait in line" for their computations.

I'd like to find a way to make the processes independent of each other. Can someone recommend the best way to do this? Do I need to use something like subprocess? Or is there a method within Django that would allow me to run independent processes?

Comment: Hi Emma! I think you need to go into much more detail, as it's very hard to understand what you're asking. I, at least, have no understanding of why your processes are colliding. Please include one detailed example of what you're doing and what's going wrong, including code.

Comment: "I don't need to go into details of how this module works"—I think maybe you do. Different users' requests don't generally interfere with each other. We need a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry Greg and Chris, I hope my edits make things more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the spicepy library that you are using - spicepy is mixing up calls sent from different Django threads. Looks [from this issue](https://github.com/AndrewAnnex/SpiceyPy/issues/107) like it doesn't support multithreading.

The way to verify this would be to disable threading in Django, and see whether that resolves the issue. How you do that depends on which wsgi server you are using in production. With uwsgi for example, you'd add this to your configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 4
threads = 1
```

(Where you are adding multiple processes to compensate for disabling threads - so that blocking one process with an expensive operation doesn't prevent anyone else from accessing it).

The Django development server also doesn't use multithreading, so if you are not able to reproduce the issue there then it would point to this being the issue.

There may some performance impact to disabling multithreading, which you can mitigate by running multiple processes. Not ideal, but not disastrous either.

Comment: This is so super helpful. Thank you so much. 

One note, I think the Django Develoment actually IS multi-threaded, by default. From Django 1.4 Release notes : "The development server is now is multithreaded by default. Use the runserver --nothreading option to disable the use of threading in the development server:"

I do see the problem go away if I use the --nothreading option, BUT it is quirky. A second process will indeed wait for the first process to complete, but in some cases the second process just stalls and nothing happens. But we will give the multi-processing a try. Thank you!